# How does zeit/pkg bundle my node application?

Tags: node.js, angular5, packaging, zeit-pkg

This is my first question on SO so first of all a BIG HELLO and please excuse in case my question doesn't fit all critereas or seems akward.

I would like to know how my app is bundled and compiled with zeit's pkg.

Is the bundle inserted into the pre-sized binary?

Does it download the node sources like nexe and is code run as main or ist the snapshot loaded when the binary is executed?

I have a backend node-express server and a frontend angular app with each having their own node_modules folder like so:

```
myapp
 |-------/client
 |          |
 |          |-----/e2e
 |          |-----/node_modules
 |          |-----/src
 |           
 |-------/config 
 |
 |-------/node_modules
 |
 |-------/routes
 |
 |--app.js
 |
 |--package.json
 |
 |--README.md
```

How does pkg treat those two instnces of node_modules?

Your help/expertise is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The fact that there are several `node_modules` doesn't matter. In app.js, `require('foo')` refers to `myapp/node_modules/foo`. Modules are bundled in a similar way they are resolved when they are loaded.

`pkg` packages only modules that are specified explicitly. As [the documentation](https://github.com/zeit/pkg#config) states,

> During packaging process pkg parses your sources, detects calls to
>   require, traverses the dependencies of your project and includes them
>   into executable. In most cases you don't need to specify anything
>   manually. However your code may have require(variable) calls (so
>   called non-literal argument to require) or use non-javascript files
>   (for example views, css, images etc).
>
> ```
>   require('./build/' + cmd + '.js')
>   path.join(__dirname, 'views/' + viewName)
> ```
>
> Such cases are not handled by pkg. So you must specify the files -
>   scripts and assets - manually in `pkg` property of your package.json
>   file.
>
> ```
>   "pkg": {
>     "scripts": "build/**/*.js",
>     "assets": "views/**/*"
>   }
> ```
>
> Just be sure to call `pkg package.json` or `pkg .` to make use of scripts
>   and assets entries.

Not doing that will result in a warning during packaging:

> Dynamic require may fail at run time, because the requested file is unknown at compilation time and not included into executable.   Use
>   a string literal as an argument for 'require', or leave it   as is and
>   specify the resolved file name in 'scripts' option.